# populating datagridview with files in multiple subfolderse

Tags: c#, recursion, datagridview, filesystems

I'm confronted with a design problem in my attempt to populate my `datagridview` with simple files.

I've declared a main directory in my `Settings` file. I need my `datagridview` to search through this parent directory in 7 subfolders. Each subfolder has a bunch of subfolders (names of machines I am managing). Each of those has contained in it the file I need to add to my grid.

Example:

`C:\Users\me\Documents\MASTERDIRECTORY\Folder7\Machine Name1\file.txt`

`C:\Users\me\Documents\MASTERDIRECTORY\Folder7\Machine Name2\file.txt`

Obviously some kind of recursive code is needed to perform the search, but how should I start? Performance wise, should I add these file paths to an array list and then translate that to my grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may help :-

```
string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\MASTERDIRECTORY\Folder7"

                foreach (string Folder in Directory.GetDirectories(filePath))
                {

                  foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Folder))
                     {
                       // here you can grab the log file path and add it to you Gridview
                     }

                }
```

Comment: Or you can build an Array / List then add use that as your Datasource for your Gridview.